# Excluding multiple variables

Tags: powershell

I need to exclude a few folders when listing some product versions in Powershell.

I've managed to get it to work for one exclusion but cannot seem to make it work for multiple.

```
function VersionInfoTest {
    $Path = 'F:\Shares\Payments*\bin'
    $Exclude1 = "F:\Shares\PaymentsCha*"

    $Results = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | where FullName -NotLike $Exclude1 | ForEach-Object {
        $Site = $_.fullname.substring(18, 3)
        $Version = dir F:\Shares\Payments$Site\bin\*App.dll | % { $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion } 

        [pscustomobject]@{
            "Site ID" = $Site
            "Version" = $Version
        }
    }

    $Results | Format-Table -AutoSize 

    $Results | Export-Csv 'VersionInfoTest.csv' -NoTypeInformation

    $Results | ConvertTo-HTML -Property 'Site ID', 'Version' | Set-Content VersionInfoTest.html
}
```

Below is the code I've tried to make it work for multiple but it does not do the job sadly. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
function VersionInfoTest {  
    $Path = 'F:\Shares\Payments*\bin'
    $Exclude1 = "F:\Shares\PaymentsCha*"
    $Exclude2 = "F:\Shares\PaymentsPor*"
    $Exclude3 = "F:\Shares\PaymentsSma*"
    $Exclude4 = "F:\Shares\PaymentsWCF*"

    $Results = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | where FullName -NotLike $Exclude1, $Exclude2, $Exclude3, $Exclude4 | ForEach-Object {
        $Site = $_.fullname.substring(18, 3)
        $Version = dir F:\Shares\Payments$Site\bin\*App.dll | % { $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion } 

        [pscustomobject]@{
            "Site ID" = $Site
            "Version" = $Version
        }
    }

    $Results | Format-Table -AutoSize 

    $Results | Export-Csv 'VersionInfoTest.csv' -NoTypeInformation

    $Results | ConvertTo-HTML -Property 'Site ID', 'Version' | Set-Content VersionInfoTest.html
}
```

Comment: It should be `Where-Object { $_.FullName -NotLike $Exclude1 -and $_.FullName -NotLike  $Exclude2 $_.FullName -NotLike $Exclude3 }` ... and so on. ☝ If you used complete paths you could use an array and the comparison operator `-contains` or `-in`.  ‍♂️

Comment: As the ignored paths fit a fairly simple pattern, you could try using a RegEx: `$pattern = "F:\\Shares\\Payments(Cha|Por|Sma|WCF).+"`, then your filter would work like this: `Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $pattern}`

Comment: Thanks for the comments Olaf and boxdog but sadly none of these seem to work. I get the error regarding unexpected $_ for yours Olaf and for the boxdog I get it complaining about an unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: @Chris Could you update your question with the exact code you used and the complete error message?

Comment: Actually @Olaf it worked. There was one -and missing! Thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  Have a nice day. 

Comment: Make sure you include the double-backslashes  for the path as it is the RegEx escape character, you need to escape it for it to be treated as a normal backslash.  That is uses `"F:\\Shares\\Payments(Cha|Por|Sma|WCF).+"` and _not_ `"F:\Shares\Payments(Cha|Por|Sma|WCF).+"`.  Also, I did notice a slight error - in your case you need to spicify `FullName` in the filter: `Where-Object {$_.FullName -notmatch $pattern}`

Comment: Thankyou boxdog, that also worked now!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should check every value against all exclusions. When first match found, stop checking this value against other exclusions and continue with next value.

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue' # Enable verbose output

$values = @(
    'Leanne Graham'
    'Ervin Howell'
    'Clementine Bauch'
    'Patricia Lebsack'
    'Chelsey Dietrich'
    'Mrs. Dennis Schulist'
    'Kurtis Weissnat'
    'Nicholas Runolfsdottir V'
    'Glenna Reichert'
    'Clementina DuBuque')

$exclusionMasks = @(
    '*Howell'
    '*Dennis*')

$newValues = @($values | 
    Where-Object { 
        foreach ($excl in $exclusionMasks) {
            if ($_ -like $excl) {
                Write-Verbose "$_ was excluded by exclusion mask $excl"
                return $false  #  This will stop execution of Where-Object scriptblock also returning $false meaning to drop value
            }
        }; 
        return $true
    })
```

---

Alternatively if exclusions list is hardcoded and short, you can achieve the same more readable way by pipelining every `Where-Object` clause into single pipeline.

```
$newValues = @($values | 
    Where-Object { $_ -notlike '*Howell*' } |
    Where-Object { $_ -notlike '*Dennis*' } |
    Where-Object { $_ -notlike '*Martha*' } 
)
```

---

For complex objects you can use complex clauses:

```
$newFileList = @($fileList | 
    Where-Object { $_.FullName -notlike 'F:\Shares\PaymentsCha*' } |
    Where-Object { $_.FullName -notlike 'F:\Shares\PaymentsPor*' } |
    Where-Object { $_.WhenCreared -lt [DateTime]::Today } |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -notlike '*John*Ripper*' } |
    Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.txt' })
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply filimonic, looks very interesting but I'm unsure how to implement this into my code! I'll see what I can achieve and get back to you.